# Assigning php variable to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to assign a php variable to javascript variable.

```
<?php 
  $type =1;  
  $form = ' <script>                
             var jquery_type " <?php = $type;  ?>";
           </script>';            
?>
```

But in source page, it is showing like below,

`var jquery_type  " <?php = $type;  ?>" ;`

How can i get this php value ?

Comment: you're "already" in php here and you're doing `<?php = $type;  ?>`. That alone should have thrown you an error.

Comment: ......... oh the one you didn't explain why it's failing them? where no one explained I mean.

Comment: drop-in code (below) doesn't do much to let them know why their code failed in the first place and are low-quality.

Answer (score 4):

@RanaRubel You received negative votes on your question because, to a respected developer, it is just plain stupid. Applications in PHP, run on a server machine, has it's own variable scope that is totally different from JavaScript variable scope (run on your local computer, a different machine).

- You can't pass variables even from same scopes in one programming languages
- Further more, it's doubly impossible to pass variables from one runtime environment (PHP) to another (JavaScript).
- Even further more, it's triply impossible to pass variables from one machine to another.

That's why you got negative votes.

What you're really trying to do is pass **data**, not variables. There are quite several ways to do so:

### 1. Render the data in the body

When rendering a PHP page, also render the data inside website body. You can, for example render a plain JavaScript name or an input field

```
<?php
    $data = "Yolo";
    echo "<script>var data = $data;<script>";
?>
```

or you can render an input field

```
<?php
    $data = "Yolo";
    echo "<input id='data' value='$data'/>";
?>
<script>
    var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
</script>
```

This is rather crude and amateur way to pass data.

### 2. Set a cookie

Cookies are even more advanced way of sending data, because they don't interfere with your application view-model. They're plain data. You can even easily read them in Developer Console.

```
<?php
    $data = "Yolo";
    setcookie("data", $data);
?>
<script>
    var data = document.cookie;
</script>
```

Not as bad as rendering data in the body, but not used because Ajax calls are more professional, more versatile and provide more control of the data flow.

### 3. Call an Ajax

This is the most sophisticated method, it gives the programmer the most control over how data is retrieved, stored and sent. This is how modern front-end frameworks like Angular, React or Vue.js work.

`script.php`:

```
<?php
    $data = "Yolo";
    echo $data;
?>
```

`script.js`:

```
<script>
    fetch('/your-script.php')
      .then(response => {
          var data = response;
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('Error loading data', err));
</script>
```

Keep in mind that `fetch()` method only works in newer browsers. In older you'd need to use `XMLHttpRequest` or use JQuery.

### 4. Assign a `<meta>` tag

This is another way of rendering in a data, and it should be used for more document/web page information, and not to pass data that is business logic. This is slightly better than rendering in a raw JavaScript variable or an input, because they can mess up your html/css structure and then your layout. `<meta>` tags aren't rendered so they can't mess your layout structure.

```
<?php
  $data = 'Yolo';
  echo "<meta name='data' content='$data' />";
?>
<script>
  var meta = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['data'];        
  var data = meta.getAttribute('content');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> You did wrong there in your script, you can not use PHP tag inside PHP.
>
> Unmanage single `(')` and double `(")` quotes, which cause `syntax error, unexpected '='`

*See this code*

```
<?php 
   $type =1;
   $form = '<script> var jquery_type = '.$type.'</script>';
   echo $form;
?>
```

OR

if you want to just only assign and use `$type` value into script than the below code is works.

```
<script>
   var jquery_type = '<?php echo $type ?>';
<script>
```

Comment: your first one will fail; that will produce a parse error.

Answer (score 0):

within php code :

```
$type = 1;  
$form =   '<script>                
            var jquery_type =  "'.$type.'";
            alert(jquery_type);
        </script>';
echo $form;
```

If its js file.

```
var jquery_type =  " <?php echo $type; ?>";
```

Comment: $Appu Amruth , thanks, its worked. But why have i got negetive marking for my question? What can i do now?

Answer (score 0):

from my experience the most universal solution always working, is this:

```
<html>
...
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenID" value="<?=$myPhpVar;?>" />
....
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var x = document.getElementById("hiddenID").value;
</script>
...
</html>
```